# how to use N cookie authentication middlewares in aspnetcore

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, middleware

I would like to use the cookie middleware for authentication to store a cookie in aspnet core.

I have a tenant namespace/id for each request, so a single user could be signed in to N cookies.

I would like to be able to use `HttpContext.SignInAsync` and `HttpContext.Authenticateasync` with this `namespace/id`.

I do not know all `namespace/ids` beforehand. is it possible to set that up with the authentication middleware?

`SigninAsync("myschem" + namespaceid) ect.`

if not possible. What would my 'Helper.SignInAsync' and 'Helper.AuthenticateAsync' look like to set the cookies myself and not use the middleware.

Reasons to use the framework is that it takes care of all the protection of cookies and setting all the cookies settings that I otherwise would have to do myself. Could one possible tab into this? So defining one scheme and then per request alter the cookie name based on the tenantid?